# How to do JSON Schema multi level conditional Validation with Array Elements

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm working on a JSON schema and I'm stuck on array validations. I have this example input JSON

```
{
  "paths_1": {
    "path_1": [
      {
        "abc": "valid_abc"
      },
      {
        "abc": "invalid_abc"
      }
    ]
  },
  "paths_2": {
    "path_2": [
      {
        "ghi": "valid_ghi"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My rule for this JSON data is, if `paths_2.path_2[].ghi` is "valid_ghi" and `paths_1.path_1[].abc` is "valid_abc", then require "def" key for the object that has "valid_abc".

I created this JSON schema for this rule, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "paths_1": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "items": {
          "properties": {
            "path_1": {
              "properties": {
                "abc": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "def": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "paths_2": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "items": {
          "properties": {
            "path_2": {
              "properties": {
                "ghi": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "properties": {
              "paths_1": {
                "properties": {
                  "path_1": {
                    "contains": {
                      "properties": {
                        "abc": {
                          "const": "valid_abc"
                        }
                      },
                      "required": [
                        "abc"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "properties": {
              "paths_2": {
                "properties": {
                  "path_2": {
                    "contains": {
                      "properties": {
                        "ghi": {
                          "const": "valid_ghi"
                        }
                      },
                      "required": [
                        "ghi"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "paths_1": {
            "properties": {
              "path_1": {
                "items": {
                  "required": [
                    "def"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I tested this schema, it returns 'def' is a required property for the object with "invalid_abc", when it should not.

I tried changing *contains* keys to *items* in JSON schema but in this case, if part becomes false and validator returns that input is valid.

Is there a way to validate this input with the given rule?

Comment:  Thank you for providing a good question with enough information to answer. I'll tidy up your question a little for formatting, but otherwise, great! Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for `valid_abc` in `items` again.

Your `then` clause has no context, which I think is what you're expecting.

```
           "items": {
              "if": {
                "properties": {
                  "abc": {
                    "const": "valid_abc"
                  }
                },
                "required": [
                  "abc"
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                "required": [
                  "def"
                ]
              }
            }
```

Demo: https://jsonschema.dev/s/M3cvJ

As a result, you can simplify your conditional checking, as you don't need to check if the array contains an object with `valid_abc`. You can remove `if/allOf[0]`, and unwrap the `allOf` as it will then only have one subschema.